# Como atribuir uma função com parâmetros ao clique sem executa-la?

Tags: javascript, jquery

## Explicação:

Possuo uma aplicação que tem por padrão um evento `mostraGrupos()` e quando ela é executada, ao final ela se desprende do elemento e tenta atribuir a função `escondeGrupos()` ao mesmo elemento.

## Código:

```
function mostraProdutosGrupo(g,elemento) {
  //codigo que mostra os produtos
  elemento.unbind();
  elemento.click(escondeProdutosGrupo(g,elemento)); //aqui ela é atribuida porem executada tambem
}

function escondeProdutosGrupo(g,elemento) {
  //codigo que esconde os produtos
  elemento.unbind();
  elemento.click(mostraProdutosGrupo(g,elemento)); //aqui ela é atribuida porem executada tambem
}
```

## Problema:

Ao tentar atribuir a função `escondeGrupos()` ao meu elemento ela é atribuida porém também é executada no momento da atribuição (isso não pode acontecer)

## Pergunta:

Como fazer com que a função `escondeGrupos()` seja atribuida ao meu elemento sem que ela seja executada no momento da atribuição? Tem como resolver este problema?

Comment: Passe como callback, assim: `elemento.click(mostraProdutosGrupo);`, sem fazer a chamada.

Comment: e os parametros... como ficam

Comment: pode por um exemplo no [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), com o código do elemento html que delega o primeiro evento?

Comment: Pelo que entendi você quer `bindar` um evento ao objeto e ao mesmo tempo `guardar` alguns parâmetros para serem usados posteriormente, é isso?

Comment: Isso @Cahe exatamente

Comment: Leia sobre a função [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

Comment: Podes dar um exemplo do teu HTML e de como estás a chamar a função  `mostraProdutosGrupo`?

Comment: Isto está sem resposta satisfatória desde 2014? Basta colocar `function(){mostraProdutosGrupo(g,elemento)}` no lugar de `mostraProtudosGrupo(g,elemento)`. Já positivei a resposta que vai direto ao ponto, a do Rubico, mas estou comentando porque ela pode ficar escondida no meio das outras.

Answer (score 7):

Após seus comentários, eu criaria um gerenciador do evento, que teria como responsabilidade obter o evento (no caso de click), e chamar a função necessária, a partir de alguns critérios. Assim diminuiria a complexidade em seu código.

Minha solução de forma básica seria assim:

```js
$(seletor).click(function(ev){
    var g = {cookie: "cookie"}
    if(ev.target.my_event){
        ev.target.my_event(g, ev.target);
    }else{
        mostraProdutosGrupo(g, ev.target);
    }
});
```

E as suas funções ficariam assim:

```js
function mostraProdutosGrupo(g,elemento) {
  //codigo que mostra os produtos
  elemento.my_event = escondeProdutosGrupo;
}

function escondeProdutosGrupo(g,elemento) {
  //codigo que esconde os produtos
  elemento.my_event = mostraProdutosGrupo; 
}
```

[Exemplo online](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/363sR/1/)

> Isso é só uma das soluções possíveis, acredito que assim terá menos problemas do que ficar removendo e adicionando evento a todo momento.
>
> Você também poderia utilizar [data-* attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) para armazenar os eventos.

Comment: ficou confuso de entender, não consegui entender a parte do my_event o que seria o atributo my_event? e em que ocasião esse `if (ev.target.my_event` daria true ou false?

Comment: @PauloRoberto, vamos lá: 1 - O `my_event`, seria uma variável/atributo para armazenar o evento no elemento. Certo? 2 - O `if(ev.target.my_event)` é para o primeiro clique, quando a variável/atributo `my_event` do elemento estará `undefined`, já que quem atribui o evento a ela é a `mostraProdutosGrupo` e `escondeProdutosGrupo` e no momento do primeiro clique nenhuma delas foi chamada. Ajudou? Já observou o exemplo no jsfiddle? Para entender melhor você pode usar o Dev Tools do browser e debuggar a solução.

Answer (score 6):

Cara, com apenas algumas modificações consegui o resultado que imagino que você queira.

```
function mostraProdutosGrupo(g,elemento) {
    console.log('mostra');
    //codigo que mostra os produtos
    elemento.unbind();
    elemento.click(function(){
        escondeProdutosGrupo(g,elemento)
    });
}

function escondeProdutosGrupo(g,elemento) {
    console.log('esconde');
    //codigo que esconde os produtos
    elemento.unbind();
    elemento.click(function(){
        mostraProdutosGrupo(g,elemento)
    });
}
```

**Explicações:**

Quando você passa a linha `elemento.click(mostraProdutosGrupo(g, Elemento));` você está pedindo para que a funcao `mostraProdutosGrupo` seja executada e que o seu resultado (retorno) seja passado como parametro para funcao `click`.

Alterando para `elemento.click(function(){mostraProdutosGrupo(g, Elemento);});` você está passando uma funcao como parametro e não a chamada dela.

**IMPORTANTE:**

Lembrando que se você fizer o bind do seu evento click pelo HTML, você não conseguirá utilizar o unbind.

Então não utilize isso:

```
<button id='botao' onclick="mostraProdutosGrupo(event, $(this));">Botao</button>
```

Mas sim isso:

```
<button id='botao'>Botao</button>

<script>
    $('#botao').click(function(){
        mostraProdutosGrupo(event, $(this));
    });
</script>
```

**Referências:**

[jQuery API .click()](https://api.jquery.com/click/)

Comment: está é a resposta com código mais limpo, recomendo como a resposta correta

Answer (score 4):

Acredito que basta mudar a sintaxe:

```
function mostraProdutosGrupo(g,elemento) {
    //codigo que mostra os produtos
    elemento.unbind();
    elemento.click(escondeProdutosGrupo); // aqui
}

function escondeProdutosGrupo(g,elemento) {
    //codigo que esconde os produtos
    elemento.unbind();
    elemento.click(mostraProdutosGrupo);// e aqui
}
```

Comment: e os parâmetros como ficam?

Comment: @PauloRoberto, o que são esses parâmetros de onde vem?

Comment: eles vem da chamada da função. quando eu atribuo o `mostraProdutosGrupo()` pela primeira vez no evento onload da pagina, o `elemento` é o `this` que pega o elemento em si que clicou, e o `g` é um valor de um cookie

Comment: nesse caso você deve pensar na solução do Fernando, eventos de elementos só devem ter parâmetros relativos à plataforma web (estado do cursor ou elemento DOM), ou sem nenhum parâmetro, tentei demonstrar apenas como não chamar a função passando-a como parâmetro :)

Answer (score 2):

Imagino que você quer fazer um "toggle".

```js
function callback1(param1, param2){
  console.log(arguments);
  jQuery('#group').hide();
}

function callback2(param1, param2){
  console.log(arguments);
  jQuery('#group').show();
}


jQuery('#toggle').on('click', function(){
  var _this    = jQuery('#group');
  var visible  = _this.is(':visible');
  if(visible){
    callback1(this, _this);
  }else{
    callback2(this, _this);
  }
});
```

```css
#group{
  width:150px;
  height:50px;
  border:1px solid #CCC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="toggle" type="button" value="toggle"/>
<div id="group">
   Produto
</div>
```

Comment: Se apegue mais ao título da pergunta e menos ao exemplo e a função que estou utilizando, eu só quero descobrir como faço para bindar função com parâmetro sem que ela execute quando eu faça isso, **apenas**, o que a função vai fazer não é relevante.

Comment: @PauloRoberto Veja se assim serve.

Answer (score 2):

**Espero que seja isso!**

Usei esse arquivo HTML para testar:
*Obs: as mensagens serão mostradas no console do navegador (F12)*

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Untitled</title>
        <style>
        li {padding:5px; border-bottom: 1px solid #EEE; cursor:pointer; color:#999;}
        li:hover {border-color: #DDD; color:#000;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>


    <ul>
    <li onclick="mostraProdutosGrupo('grupo', this)">Ítem um</li>
    <li onclick="mostraProdutosGrupo('grupo', this)">Ítem dois</li>
    <li onclick="mostraProdutosGrupo('grupo', this)">Ítem tres</li>
    <li onclick="mostraProdutosGrupo('grupo', this)">Ítem quatro</li>
    </ul>

        <script>

        function mostraProdutosGrupo(g,elemento) {
            console.log('mostra: '+elemento.innerHTML);//somente debug - delete me
            setAttOnClick(elemento, "escondeProdutosGrupo('"+g+"', this)");
        }

        function escondeProdutosGrupo(g,elemento) {
            console.log('esconde: '+elemento.innerHTML);//somente debug - delete me
            setAttOnClick(elemento, "mostraProdutosGrupo('"+g+"', this)");
        }

        //Faz um "update" do atributo "onclick"
        function setAttOnClick(e, val){
            var at  = document.createAttribute('onclick');
            at.value = val;
            e.attributes.setNamedItem(at);
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Esta é uma dúvida muito comum em Javascript.

> Como fazer com que a função escondeGrupos() seja atribuida ao meu
>   elemento sem que ela seja executada no momento da atribuição? Tem como
>   resolver este problema?

### Entendendo o problema

Primeiramente, você tem que entender o porquê de sua função ser executada no momento da atribuição. Vamos para um exemplo mais simples:

```
function soma(x, y) {
  return x + y;
}

soma(5, soma(3, 2));
```

Quando você lê o código acima, você com certeza entende que você não está passando a função `soma` como parâmetro pra ela mesmo, e sim o resultado da execução de dentro. Então, você leria o código acima como `soma(5, soma(3, 2)) = soma(5, 5) = 10`.

Ou seja, quando você está fazendo `elemento.click(escondeProdutosGrupo(g,elemento));`, você está chamando a função escondeProdutosGrupo com estes parâmetros em específico, e o resultado desta função (que no caso provavelmente é um void), você está passando como parâmetro para a função `click` do jQuery.

Existem algumas formas de resolver esta situação:

### Opção 1: Função anônima

A mais comum e simples é você encapsular o código a ser executado em uma função anônima:

```
elemento.click(function() {
  escondeProdutosGrupo(g, elemento);
});
```

Nesse caso, você está passando para o evento `click` uma função que será executada, e esta função chamará o `escondeProdutosGrupo` conforme você espera que aconteça.

### Opção 2: Function.prototype.bind

A partir do ES5, você tem a opção de usar o método `bind` que existe em todas as instâncias de função da linguagem. Você passa como primeiro parâmetro para este método aquilo que você gostaria que fosse o `this` dentro daquele método (passe `null` se não quiser mudar o escopo, ou se isso não for importante para a sua questão). E os demais parâmetros serão os parâmetros que serão passados para a chamada daquela função.

```
elemento.click(escondeProdutosGrupo.bind(null, g, elemento));
```

Desta forma, você está passando como parâmetro a função em si, já carregada com seus futuros parâmetros, que serão executadas quando o evento `click` ocorrer.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente, não ficou claro o suficiente como é feita a primeira chamada desse seu método e de onde vem esses parâmetros iniciais. Se essa informação estivesse presente, seria mais fácil dar uma resposta mais assertiva.

O que eu sugiro é que utilize uma classe `CSS` para realizar a mudança de estado de visualização dos produtos.

Abaixo elaborei um exemplo para mostrar um possível método para resolver o seu problema.

**HTML**

```
<div class="elemento">
  <label>Grupo A - <a href="#" data-id-grupo="10">Exibir produtos</a></label>
  <ul class="produtos oculto">
    <li>Elemento 1</li>
    <li>Elemento 2</li>
    <li>Elemento 3</li>
    <li>Elemento 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.produtos.oculto {
  display: none;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('.elemento a').on('click', function()
{
    var $elemento = $(this);
  ///Você pega o ID do grupo ou qualquer informação que desejar do elemento
  var idGrupo = $elemento.data('id-grupo');

    ///Se necessário nesse momento pode-se fazer a
  //requisição ajax dos produtos do grupo, caso
  //eles ainda não tenham sido carregados, ou
  //necessite de atualização

    var $produtos = $elemento.parent().siblings('.produtos');
  $produtos.toggleClass('oculto');

  if ($produtos.hasClass('oculto'))
  {
    $elemento.html('Exibir produtos - Grupo ' + idGrupo);
  }
  else
  {
    $elemento.html('Ocultar produtos - Grupo ' + idGrupo);
  }
});
```

Como não há mais detalhes sobre a sua implementação, coloquei o ID do grupo de produtos como um `data-attribute` e resgato o mesmo no click no link.

Caso seja necessário, resgate os produtos via `ajax` e depois insira no `HTML` para exibir.

Caso os produtos já estejam carregados, basta usar as classes `CSS` para exibir/ocultar os produtos.

Qualquer nova consideração eu vou alterando o exemplo.

Se quiser ele está disponível aqui nesse [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/richarddias/5kfo3jxz/) para exemplificar.

Answer (score 1):

A maneira que encontrei para adicionar uma **função** ao **click** de um **elemento**, sem chamar essa função quando atribuida, é adicionando um **EventListener**.

```
element.addEventListener(event, function, useCapture)
```

Porem para **remover** o evento do elemento, o mais **elegante** que encontrei é clonando o elemento, onde ao clonar, é perdido todos seus EventListener. 
Existem outra maneira para remover, caso a função fosse sem paramentros. 
Segue **removeEventListener**: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_removeeventlistener.asp

A função ficaria assim:

```
function mostraProdutosGrupo(g,elemento) {
    //codigo que mostra os produtos
    $("#myBtn").replaceWith($('#myBtn').clone()); 
    document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function() { escondeProdutosGrupo(g,elemento); }); // Aqui é atribuido um novo EventListener.
}

function escondeProdutosGrupo(g,elemento) {
    //codigo que esconde os produtos
    $("#myBtn").replaceWith($('#myBtn').clone());
    document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function() { mostraProdutosGrupo(g,elemento); });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Posso te recomendar duas formas que não atrapalhariam a legibilidade do seu código...

## Criar uma função "preparadora" para seus eventos

```
function mostraProdutosGrupo(g,elemento) {
  //codigo que mostra os produtos
  elemento.unbind();
  elemento.click(prepararEsconderProdutosGrupo(g,elemento)); //aqui ela é atribuida porem executada tambem
}

function escondeProdutosGrupo(g,elemento) {
  //codigo que esconde os produtos
  elemento.unbind();
  elemento.click(prepararMostrarProdutosGrupo(g,elemento)); //aqui ela é atribuida porem executada tambem
}

function prepararMostrarProdutosGrupo(g, element){
     return function(){
         mostraProdutosGrupo(g, element);
     };
}

 function prepararEsconderProdutosGrupo(g, element){
     return function(){
         esconderProdutosGrupo(g, element);
     };
}
```

## Usando a função .bind nas funções

uma outra forma, mais atual de se abordar isso é usando o `.bind` (https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```
function mostraProdutosGrupo(g,elemento) {
  //codigo que mostra os produtos
  elemento.unbind();
  elemento.click(escondeProdutosGrupo.bind(this, g,elemento)); //aqui ela é atribuida porem executada tambem
}

function escondeProdutosGrupo(g,elemento) {
  //codigo que esconde os produtos
  elemento.unbind();
  elemento.click(mostraProdutosGrupo.bind(this, g,elemento)); //aqui ela é atribuida porem executada tambem
}
```

Eu particularmente, num cenário onde isso não irá ser tão comum, usaria o `.bind()`para facilitar o entendimento.

Mas se você tem isso com muita frequência é mais interessante criar algo para gerenciar seus eventos